# what i should i do to correct this code please ? As output, i have to obtain invalid input and then the maximum and the minimum value

Tags: python, try-except

```
minimum = None
maximum = None
try:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == done : break
except:
    print ("Invalid input")      

fval = float (num)
if fval > maximum:
        maximum = fval 
if minimum is None:
        minimum = fval
elif fval < minimum:
        minimum = fval
print("Maximum is", maximum)
print("Minimum is", minimum)
```

the statement of the problem I am trying to solve is the following : 
Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

Comment: How did you get the idea of using `break` without a loop? A `break` comes in handy when  you want to leave a loop, but at the moment there's no loop in your code. That's the first problem you should tackle: add a loop.to repeatedly ask for a number.

Comment: i add the while loop now

Answer (score 0):

So you need to be using a while loop if you are trying to break out of it also you need to make your value of done a string. If you run your code you get this error.

```
if num == 'done': break
                     ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

okay so this is probably what you are looking for

```
minimum = 10e+10  # cannot compare None and float
maximum = -10e+10


while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        if num.isnumeric() or float(num):
            fval = float(num)
            if fval > maximum:
                maximum = fval
            # if minimum is None: # not needed
        #         minimum = fval
            if fval < minimum:
                minimum = fval
            print("Maximum is", maximum)
            print("Minimum is", minimum)
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        if num != 'done':
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
        elif num == 'done':
            break
```

Comment: yes i tried now and as output i obtain the following : Maximum is 7.0 ← Mismatch
Minimum is 7.0
Maximum is 7.0
Minimum is 2.0
Invalid input
Maximum is 10.0
Minimum is 2.0
Maximum is 10.0
Minimum is 2.0                                                                                                                                     while the desired output is :                                                                                 Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2

Comment: So are you trying to set the minimum and maximum for the first two inputs? Then after that let the user put in the inputs and see if it is within those ranges? Also if you only want it to print the min and max when done is entered you can move the print statements under the elif num == ‘done’ block before the break.

Answer (score 0):

```
minimum = 10e+10 # cannot compare None and float
maximum = -10e+10
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done' : break # your break is not in any loop
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")      

    fval = float (num)
    if fval > maximum:
            maximum = fval 
    # if minimum is None: # not needed
    #         minimum = fval
    if fval < minimum:
            minimum = fval
    print("Maximum is", maximum)
    print("Minimum is", minimum)
```

```
Enter a number: 2
Maximum is 2.0
Minimum is 2.0
Enter a number: 10
Maximum is 10.0
Minimum is 2.0
Enter a number: done
```

Comment: i have tried your code but i doesn't work. So, it demands always to Enter a number:

Comment: yes, so this code will keep on asking for number input and give you max and min so far. But if you type done, it exits the program

Comment: yes i know but even when i type done the code eep on asking for number input.

Comment: maximum and minimum of what? you need two numbers to compare! Give sample input-output

Comment: i tried when one more time and i obtain the following output : Maximum is 2.0 ← Mismatch
Minimum is 2.0
Maximum is 10.0
Minimum is 2.0                                                                                                                                               but the output of the code should be the following :                                            
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2